# How to get all the divisible pairs in a range faster?

Tags: algorithm, performance, kotlin, math

I have a function to compute all the divisible pairs in a given range [start, end] and I would like to know if there's a way to improve the performance of it.

Here is my current implementation in Kotlin:

```
fun getDivisiblePairsInRange(
    start: Int,
    end: Int,
    ignoreSelfDivision: Boolean = false,
): List<IntArray>
{
    if (start == 0) throw IllegalArgumentException("start parameter can't be 0")

    val oneOrZero = if (ignoreSelfDivision) 1.0 else 0.0

    val divisiblePairs = mutableListOf<IntArray>()

    for (numerator in start..end)
    {
        val optimizedEnd = ceil(sqrt(numerator - oneOrZero)).toInt()

        var divisorFromPreviousIteration = -1

        for (denominator in start..optimizedEnd)
        {
            if (numerator % denominator != 0 || denominator == divisorFromPreviousIteration) continue

            divisiblePairs += intArrayOf(numerator, denominator)

            val secondDivisor = numerator / denominator

            if (!(ignoreSelfDivision && numerator == secondDivisor) && denominator != secondDivisor) divisiblePairs += intArrayOf(numerator, secondDivisor)

            divisorFromPreviousIteration = secondDivisor
        }
    }

    return divisiblePairs
}
```

As you can see the time complexity is O(n^1.5) and there's an ignoreSelfDivision to avoid getting pairs like (a, a), but it's not relevant.

These are some outputs from concrete examples to better show how the function behaves:

```
(1, 3)  -> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]
(1, 5)  -> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3], [4, 1], [4, 4], [4, 2], [5, 1], [5, 5]]
(1, 8)  -> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3], [4, 1], [4, 4], [4, 2], [5, 1], [5, 5], [6, 1], [6, 6], [6, 2], [6, 3], [7, 1], [7, 7], [8, 1], [8, 8], [8, 2], [8, 4]]
(1, 10) -> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3], [4, 1], [4, 4], [4, 2], [5, 1], [5, 5], [6, 1], [6, 6], [6, 2], [6, 3], [7, 1], [7, 7], [8, 1], [8, 8], [8, 2], [8, 4], [9, 1], [9, 9], [9, 3], [10, 1], [10, 10], [10, 2], [10, 5]]
```

---------- UPDATE ----------

This is a faster version from @Dave adapted to Kotlin:

```
fun getDivisiblePairsInRangeFromDave(
    start: Int,
    end: Int,
    ignoreSelfDivision: Boolean = false,
): List<IntArray>
{
    var ratio = end / start
    var currentDenominator = start
    val divisiblePairs = mutableListOf<IntArray>()

    while (ratio >= 1)
    {
        for (multiple in 1..ratio)
        {
            val numerator = currentDenominator * multiple

            if (ignoreSelfDivision && currentDenominator == numerator) continue

            divisiblePairs += intArrayOf(numerator, currentDenominator)
        }

        ratio = end / ++currentDenominator
    }

    return divisiblePairs
}
```

Another way of improving the performance a little bit is define a function to only get the count of pairs (it would be similar but without the mutable list of pairs) which is faster to calculate and then use an array instead of a mutable list, the improvement can be around 30%.

Comment: If you really need to list out all divisible pairs within the range, your implementation can't be improved by too much- the only speedup I can think of is simply iterating by multiples of the denominator in the outer loop so that only divisible pairs are generated; I'm not sure that would bring down the runtime complexity though. On the other hand, if you need to **count** the number of divisible pairs, that's a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is linear in the output.

Let's say end/start = r (integer division).

If r == 0 there are no solutions.

Otherwise, 1*start, 2*start, 3*start, ..., r*start are all in your range.

ditto for start+i until at some point r*(start+i) is out of range at which point you can decrement r.

Repeat until r gets decremented to 1.

Ruby code:

```
def get_pairs(first_int, last_int)
  r = last_int / first_int
  pairs = []
  cur_int = first_int
  while r >= 1
    1.upto(r) do |mult|
      pairs.append([cur_int * mult, cur_int])
    end
    cur_int += 1
    r = last_int / cur_int
  end
  return pairs.to_s
end



> get_pairs(1,3)
=> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]

get_pairs(1,5)
=> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [2, 2], [4, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]

> get_pairs(1,8)
=> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1], [2, 2], [4, 2], [6, 2], [8, 2], [3, 3], [6, 3], [4, 4], [8, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8]]

get_pairs(1,10)
=> [[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [7, 1], [8, 1], [9, 1], [10, 1], [2, 2], [4, 2], [6, 2], [8, 2], [10, 2], [3, 3], [6, 3], [9, 3], [4, 4], [8, 4], [5, 5], [10, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9], [10, 10]]
```

--- update: an example of a succinct approach ---

So this is succinct except that I'm expressing the output as long strings for clarity. For actual use, you could return pairs representing the multiple and the max integer in the range that can be multiplied by that mult and still be in range.

This is O(last_int / first_int), or linear in the number of different multiples. It could be further improved by treating 1 as a special case since everything can always be multiplied by 1 and still be in range, but I don't do that here.

```
def get_pairs_succinct(first_int, last_int)
  mult = 1
  summary = ""
  while last_int / mult >= first_int
    summary += "max int we can multiply by #{mult} and still be in-range: #{last_int / mult}\n"
    mult += 1
  end
  puts summary
end

get_pairs_succinct(1,3)
max int we can multiply by 1 and still be in-range: 3
max int we can multiply by 2 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 3 and still be in-range: 1

size of output = 3 vs 5 non-succinct

> get_pairs_succinct(1,5)
max int we can multiply by 1 and still be in-range: 5
max int we can multiply by 2 and still be in-range: 2
max int we can multiply by 3 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 4 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 5 and still be in-range: 1

size of output = 5 vs 10 non-succinct

> get_pairs_succinct(1,8)
max int we can multiply by 1 and still be in-range: 8
max int we can multiply by 2 and still be in-range: 4
max int we can multiply by 3 and still be in-range: 2
max int we can multiply by 4 and still be in-range: 2
max int we can multiply by 5 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 6 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 7 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 8 and still be in-range: 1

size of output = 8 vs 20 non-succinct

> get_pairs_succinct(1,10)
max int we can multiply by 1 and still be in-range: 10
max int we can multiply by 2 and still be in-range: 5
max int we can multiply by 3 and still be in-range: 3
max int we can multiply by 4 and still be in-range: 2
max int we can multiply by 5 and still be in-range: 2
max int we can multiply by 6 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 7 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 8 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 9 and still be in-range: 1
max int we can multiply by 10 and still be in-range: 1

size of output = 10 vs 27 non-succinct
```

Lastly, if we try this for a larger range or a range farther from one, the differences become more dramatic. E.g., for the range (10, 100):

non-succinct: output is 201 pairs, vs succinct: same information in 10 rows and proportional computation.

```
> get_pairs_succinct(10, 100)
max int we can multiply by 1 and still be in-range: 100
max int we can multiply by 2 and still be in-range: 50
max int we can multiply by 3 and still be in-range: 33
max int we can multiply by 4 and still be in-range: 25
max int we can multiply by 5 and still be in-range: 20
max int we can multiply by 6 and still be in-range: 16
max int we can multiply by 7 and still be in-range: 14
max int we can multiply by 8 and still be in-range: 12
max int we can multiply by 9 and still be in-range: 11
max int we can multiply by 10 and still be in-range: 10
```

Comment: This assumes positive integers. Or all negative. If the range crosses zero then it can be extended to handle that.

Comment: Since there ``` upto ``` it's a loop I don't see why you say it's linear.

Also the outputs are different from my function.

Comment: @EliánFabián I made the minor changes needed to make my output look like yours: reversed the order of the pairs internally (from (small, big) to (big, small)) and included self division. The reason I say it's linear in the output is because we append exactly one pair per inner loop, so the inner loop executes once per pair in the output. I added the same 4 inputs you gave in the examples so you can see this gives same results other than the order of the pairs.

Comment: @EliánFabián I also fixed a bug that occurred when r needed to decrease by more than 1 instantly; replaced r -= 1 with r = last_int / cur_int.

Comment: @EliánFabián You can't do better than linear in the output, though we could calculate the number of pairs more quickly, or if you'd be satisfied with expressing the output more succinctly this could be sped up. E.g., if you'd accept (small int, range of multiples) so that [2,2], [2,4], [2,6], [2,8] would be expressed as [2, 1, 4] or [2, 1-4] or something like that, that could also be faster by eliminating the inner loop.

Comment: I implemented it and it's a lot faster than mine, it's great, thank you @Dave!